# Get _id value using python cork

Tags: python, mongodb, bottle

it's a simple question for something who was/is using Cork and know how it works internally.
Basically inside the Cork.py script, when a User() is created, it validates for this _id in this line:

```
    if session is not None:
        try:
            self.session_creation_time = session['_creation_time']
            self.session_accessed_time = session['_accessed_time']
            self.session_id = session['_id']
        except:
            pass
```

session['_id'] is not there, I see the username in the session instead of the _id, and I want that _id for making some DBRef on my collections.

Looking at the code for Cork.py and mongodb_backend.py I don't see anything storing the _id in the session.

Can anyone help me with that? should I modify cork library?

The easiest response is to make my own query and ask for the _id using the username, but it doesn't make sense if I can encapsulate the _id and have that value inside the User() class.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you don't get any response on StackOverflow, you might want to post to the Cork [issue tracker](https://github.com/FedericoCeratto/bottle-cork/issues) list as well.

Answer (score 0):

cork.py - in login function:

```
        if username in self._store.users:
        if self._verify_password(username, password,
                self._store.users[username]['hash']):
            # Setup session data
            usr = self._store.users[username]
            self._setup_cookie(username, usr["_id"])
```

in _setup_cookie:

```
    def _setup_cookie(self, username, _id):
    """Setup cookie for a user that just logged in"""
    session = self._beaker_session
    session['username'] = username
    session['_id'] = _id
```